# Combining match on text field with aggregate

Tags: mongodb

Running the following statement:

```
db.users.aggregate(
   [
       { $match : { "confirmed" : {$eq: "true" } } },
       { $group : { _id : "$email", email: { $push: "$email" } } }
   ]
)
```

Gives me zero results, although the following one works perfectly fine giving ~12k:

```
db.getCollection('users').find({confirmed:"true"})
```

**Question:** how do I combined match and group properly? I am basically looking for a `SELECT email FROM users GROUP BY email`

**Add on:** `SELECT email, count(*) FROM users GROUP BY email` would be my long term goal, but I can't seem to get my head around mongodb :(

Comment: Can you update your question with a sample document? Also, what version is your MongoDB server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
db.users.aggregate(
   [
       { $match : { "confirmed" : "true" }  },
       { $group : { _id : "$email",count:{$sum:1} } }
   ]
)
```

`
please check if true is boolean if boolean than no need to check it as a string it will give you 0 document.just 
Confirmed:true