# How can I aggregate using a match on two different fields?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

This seems simple enough, but for some reason, when I put the second field in my match statement, my aggregation returns an empty array.

**I have checked these :**

[Combining match on text field with aggregate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40370255/combining-match-on-text-field-with-aggregate)

[Match Two different fields in Mongoose, Aggregate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48556504/match-two-different-fields-in-mongoose-aggregate)

[Mongodb compare two fields with matched fields value aggregate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53995878/mongodb-compare-two-fields-with-matched-fields-value-aggregate)

**This is what I want :**

I want a match statement that compares two fields from my schema that only return data for the createdByUserId and greater than or equal to some start date

```
$match: 
{ $and: 
  [ 
    { createdByUserId: userId }, 
    { dateStart: { $gte: new Date(startDate) } } 
  ] 
}
```

this is what it resolves out to be:

```
{
  "$match": {
    "$and": [
      {
        "createdByUserId": "5e6c2dddad72870c84f8476b"
      },
      {
        "dateStart": {
          "$gte": "2020-04-10T14:35:02.478Z"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**THIS IS WHAT I TRIED**

I tried to simplify the problem down just using createdByUserId -but- that is not working

I believe the user ID match is the crux of my problem

```
$match: 
{
    createdByUserId: userId
}
```

resolved out to be:

```
{
  "$match": {
    "createdByUserId": "5e6c2dddad72870c84f8476b"
  }
}
```

I thought it might be a 'string to object id' issue and tried this (but it didn't work)

```
$match: 
{
    createdByUserId: { $eq: {$toOjbectId:userId} }
}
```

Resolved out to be:

```
{
  "$match": {
    "createdByUserId": {
      "$eq": {
        "$toOjbectId": "5e6c2dddad72870c84f8476b"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**More info**

To show the entire pipeline, here is my aggregation:

```
var match = {
    $match: 
    { $and: 
        [ 
            { createdByUserId: userId }, 
            { dateStart: { $gte: new Date(startDate) } } 
        ] 
    }
};

var lookup ={
    $lookup:
    {
        from: "MyEvents",
        localField: "_id",
        foreignField: "eventId",
        as: "SignedUpUsers"
    }
};

var project = {
    $project: {
        "_id": 1,
        "name": 1,
        "dateStart": 1,
        "createdByUserId": 1
    }
};

var agg = [
    match,
    lookup,
    project
];

Event.aggregate(agg)
.sort({dateStart: 1})
.then( events => {
    if(events){
        return resolve(events);
    }else{
        return reject(null);
    }
})
.catch(err => {
    return reject(err);
})
```

Here is the Event Schema

```
const EventSchema = new Schema({
    name: {type: String, required: true},
    dateStart: {type: Date, required: true},
    createdByUserId: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true},
})
```

Here is MyEvents schema

```
const MyEventsSchema = new Schema({
    userId: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true},
    eventId: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true},
})
```

( there is data in the collection that should be returned )

How can I match on two different fields ?

**UPDATE**

Thanks to whoami, this works:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

 {
   $match: {
     createdByUserId: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userId);
   }
 }
```

But can anybody tell me why this doesn't change the string to an object id:

```
{$toOjbectId:userId}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes the issue should be with input is of type `string` *Vs* DB field is of type `ObjectId()`.Three ways to do it :

**One Way :** Change in aggregation query

```
 {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $eq: [
          userId,
          {
            $toString: "$createdByUserId" // Convert existing 'ObjectId()' to String
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

**Test :** [MongoDB-Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/CZIpyYFlfCC)

**Second Way :** Convert `string` to `ObjectId()` in mongoose :

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

    {
      $match: {
        createdByUserId: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userId);
      }
    }
```

**Third way :**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $eq: [
          {
            $toObjectId: "5e6c2dddad72870c84f8476b" /** Convert input to ObjectId() using aggregation */
          },
          "$createdByUserId"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

**Test :** [MongoDB-Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/-gJBFfj8PoJ)

**Issue with your query :** As `$ObjectId` is an aggregation operator - You need to use aggregation syntax in `$match`.

I would prefer second process as it might have better performance & use an index on `createdByUserId` field. Anyway you can always use `explain` to test your query performance.

Comment: Why doesn't  {$toOjbectId:userId} do the same thing as your second example ?

Comment: whoami, what would the entire match statement look like with the third way? (just to fully round out this answer )

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/7237613/whoami - I don't know why this is failing https://mongoplayground.net/p/E3oCnGHu2kE

Comment: whoami - I got it... https://mongoplayground.net/p/4rHlitxTMrs - thanks !

Comment: @MLissCetrus : Ok for your another question of *how it gets converted* - Try : `db.collection.explain().aggregate([.....])` to see how your aggregation query is working !!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/7237613/whoami - Was this a good question?  did it outline all of the necessary information required for you to come up with an answer?  If so, can you please up vote it?  thanks

Answer (score 0):

**You can Follow This Code**

```
$match: {
    $and: [
      {
        "createdByUserId": "5e6c2dddad72870c84f8476b"
      },
      {
        "dateStart": {
          $gte: "2020-04-10T14:35:02.478Z"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```